# batch to copy files with xcopy

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have checked some examples on internet but I can't get my (first) batch file to work. I would like to copy automatically my file from a folder to another one but nothing happen.

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\source\" "C:\target\" /c /d /i /y
exit
```

Could you see anything wrong?

Thanks!!

Update: I have done the command given by Bali C but it still doesn't work. See snapshot

```
xcopy C:\folder1 C:\folder2\folder1 /t /e /i /y
xcopy C:\folder1 C:\folder2\ /t /e /i /y
```

Image:
[image]

I have to stop it with CTRL + C.

PS: I'm on Win 7

Update (Solution):
It works! The problem was the name xcopy,bat on my Desktop, and I was running the command from there, so it was executing the xcopy.bat file of my desktop instead of the Windows one.. I had to rename the file with "myxcopy.bat" :

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\source" "C:\target" /c /d /i /y
exit
```

Comment: What is the name of your batch file? From your screenshot, I'm guessing it's `XCOPY.BAT`. Try renaming to something else, like `MyXcopy.bat`.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure then, I tried the exact command you tried in the screenshot (top one from my answer) and it worked fine, straight away. Unless you don't have permissions on those folders?

Comment: Yes, if it was named `XCOPY.BAT`, that would definitely cause a problem. Every time you called `XCOPY` in your batch file, you would be calling another instance of `XCOPY.BAT` instead of the `XCOPY` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After testing most of the switches this worked for me:

```
xcopy C:\folder1 C:\folder2\folder1 /t /e /i /y
```

This will copy the folder `folder1` into the folder `folder2`. So the directory tree would look like:

```
C:
   Folder1
   Folder2
      Folder1
```

Comment: I tried removing some options or just /c /y
 But it doesn't change anything, I get the cursor blinking on the next line as well

Comment: Could you post the exact code you are using? With the filename included?

Comment: Actually, `\S` copies directories and subdirectories _except_ empty ones.

Comment: Your answer is still not right. `\S` will copy directories and subdirectories _except_ empty ones. If a directory contains files/folders, it will get copied...if a directory does not contain files/folders it will not get copied.

Comment: Lol I'm getting confused, since I'm presuming the file will be there the s switch won't cause a problem, just removed it from my answer.

Comment: I tried different combinaisons of Options but still, do you manage to do it on your own computer? I have updated my question with the content of my xcopy.bat file

Comment: The command you are using is trying to copy a folder, if you are copying a file you need to specify the file like in my answer. Are you copying a folder or a file?

Comment: I'am trying to copy a folder, containing others files and folders

Comment: Edited answer, hopefully this should fix it :)

Comment: here you can find what does /t e/ /i /y mean: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Based on xcopy help, I tried and found that following works perfectly for me (tried on Win 7)

```
xcopy C:\folder1 C:\folder2\folder1 /E /C /I /Q /G /H /R /K /Y /Z /J
```

Comment: best one for bringing over subdirectories and files at every level

Answer (score 4):

If the requirement is to copy all files in "\Publish\Appfolder" into the parent "\Publish\" folder (inclusive of any subfolders, following works for me)
The switch '/s' allows copying of all subfolders, recursively.

`xcopy src\main\Publish\Appfolder\*.*  /s src\main\Publish\`

Answer (score 3):

You must specify your file in the copy:

```
xcopy C:\source\myfile.txt C:\target
```

Or if you want to copy all txt files for example

```
xcopy C:\source\*.txt C:\target
```

Comment: I tried xcopy C:\source\*.txt C:\target
 But it doesn't change anything, I get the cursor blinking on the next line