# Copy folder to a newly created Directory using .bat

Tags: batch-file

I  create a directory using MD. Once you plug in the USB drive, you select it and it create the directory to the drive, however i am trying to copy files from the source to the new directory on usb. I have tried so many things but nothing seems to work. 
Here is the .bat file

```
@echo OFF


diskpart

set source=C:\Users\Public\Documents

set DESTINATION= %computername% %DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%/

@echo DESTINATION =%DESTINATION%

:: Create new directory
md "%1\%DESTINATION%"

xcopy %source% %DESTINATION% /y
```

It creates the directory but it doesnt copy the files from the source to the newly created directory. How can i do that? How do you pass an argument? This the first time i am writting a script.
THanks!

Comment: Are you passing any arguments to your script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114887/batch-to-copy-files-with-xcopy

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

1. You are creating the destination directory as `%1\%DESTINATION%` but in `XCOPY` you've specified just `%DESTINATION%`. It is likely that `%1\` is not the current directory at the time of copying, which must explain why the intended target directory doesn't receive any files. Therefore, you should add `%1\` in front `%DESTINATION%` in `XCOPY`.
2. The destination directory name, as set by the `SET DESTINATION` command, contains spaces. That means that the name must be enclosed in double quotes in most file operation contexts. By "most" I mean that there are some commands that do not require the names to be quoted, although I would still not recommend omitting the quotes. And `XCOPY` is not one of those commands anyway, so, your target path should actually be `"%1\%DESTINATION%"`, just like in the `MD` command.
3. Possibly not an issue but I'm not sure. You've got a space just after `=` in `SET DESTINATION` command. That space actually becomes part of the value. You'll probably want to remove it unless it was your intention that your destination directory name start with a space character.
4. Similarly half-issue, the trailing `/` at the end of the name is unnecessary. It may not be an issue in this particular script, but in general you'd have to be more careful using such a path as part of a more complex path, particularly when the name goes at the beginning or in the middle of the more complex path. It'd be less troublesome to use `\` instead or just omit the trailing separator all together.

Finally, you could possibly omit the `MD` command and let `XCOPY` create the target directory for you if it didn't exist. Add the `/I` switch to `XCOPY` to avoid the request about whether the target is a file or a directory.

Only note that if the source directory is totally empty, the target won't be created. To ensure it was created, you'd need to add `/E` also. However, that would also imply copying the entire directory structure, including empty *sub*directories, if any, as well. If that doesn't agree with your intention, stick with your current `MD` + `XCOPY` method.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it worked for me. It did copy all the files in source folder. Just assign the source and dest variables with appropriate values.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set SOURCE="C:\Users\Public\Documents"
SET DEST="%computername% %DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%"

echo %SOURCE% %DEST%

IF NOT EXIST %DEST% mkdir %DEST%

xcopy %SOURCE%\*.* %DEST%\*.* /Y
```